# How can I safely change states between state objects?

Tags: c++, state

I posted a question recently, and it was pointed out to me that I am going horribly wrong!

In `main()` I am making a state and then passing in integers to `processState()` and based on the integer it will changes state (by destroying the state and creating a new instance of a new state), or stay in the same state.

The main issue pointed out to me is in function `void state_t::changeState(state_t * new_state)`. I am deleting `this` and then pointing the deleted `_state` pointer to point to the new state.  Now that it is pointed out to me, it is obviously a bad thing to do.

So the question is:  what is the best way to achieve this kind of state switching using different states?  Maybe `_state` needs to be a global pointer to the current state or some such?

**`Main.cpp`**:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "statemachine.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    state_t *myState = new testState1();

    myState = myState->processState(1);
    myState = myState->processState(2);
    myState = myState->processState(3);
    myState = myState->processState(1);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Base type:

```
#include "state_t.h"

state_t::state_t(QByteArray stateName) :
    name(stateName),
    _state(this)
{
    qDebug() << this->name << ": Creating state";
}

state_t::~state_t()
{
    qDebug() << this->name << ": Deleting state";
    qDebug() << endl;
}

void state_t::changeState(state_t * new_state)
{
    // Check if the state has changed
    if (this != new_state)
    {
        qDebug() << this->name << ": State changed to: " << new_state->name;
        delete this;
        _state = new_state;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << this->name << ": State un-changed";
    }
}

void state_t::unknownStateEventHandler(int event)
{
    qWarning() << this->name << ": Unknown event " << event;
}
```

A state class (there can be many of these):

```
#include "teststate1.h"

testState1::testState1() :
    state_t("state1")
{
}

state_t *testState1::processState(int event)
{
    qDebug() << name << ": event" << event;
    switch (event)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            changeState(new testState2());
            //changeState_t(testState2);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            unknownStateEventHandler(event);
            break;
        }
    }

    return _state;
}
```

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth: It's "all hail". We can all be grateful the times where people yelled "heil" are over. ;)

Comment: @thokra well that was an unpleasant spelling fail, thank you, I just removed the comment :)

Comment: @thokra & Scarlet ... lol :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you've got is that you're mixing-up the behaviour of a state with the behaviour of the state machine; i.e. executing state behaviour, vs. managing state changes. Those should be kept separate.

You could have a class which represents your state machine as a whole. It doesn't have any state-specific functionality inside. Rather, it will contain a pointer to the current state object. (I'm assuming all your individual state classes are derived from a common base class.)

When you want to change state, the state machine class will delete the old state and create and/or store the new one. The individual state classes shouldn't be doing that directly, although they could call a function on the state machine to initiate the change.

As a side note, it's best to avoid using `delete this`. It technically works, but it's usually not a good idea.

Comment: Instance suicide should, if ever, be used very cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should not do

```
delete this;
_state = new_state;
```

You should just assign the value of new_state to this by:

```
*this = *new_state
```

But I don't think this is a good design. Please check this [example](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/cpp/1).

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but in my case this does not achieve the goal because I specifically want to delete the "old/current" state and then instantiate the new one. The link is, however very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to implement it too and I have some doubts too but as far as I understand you are committing some design mistakes.

This design pattern defines the following **partecipants**:

- **context** defines the interface of interest to clients and maintains an instance of a
  `ConcreteState` subclass that defines the current state.
- **`State`** defines an interface for encapsulating the behaviour associated with a a particular state.
- **`ConcreteState`** subclasses: each subclass implementing a behaviour associated with a state of the context.

The goal is that the context does not have to worry about which state it is in: it uses the general interface delegating the specific operations to the `ConcreteState` subclasses. Plus you can extend your program by adding a new state without having to modify the context and the rest of the code.

The state in C++ is represented by a member variable in the `Context`, your "machine", of type `State` which is a base class, possibly abstract. Defining a pointer of parent class type exploits polymorphism, allowing you to reference the `ConcreteState` subclasses.

For example let me define the following `State` class (note it has a reference to the `Context` class) defining the interface for all the `ConcreteState` subclasses. (I defined the methods as virtual it is not mandatory):

```
#ifndef INPUTSTATE_H
#define INPUTSTATE_H
#include "Context.hpp"

using namespace std;
class Context;

class State
{
public:
  State(Context* context);
  virtual void method1(int x, int y);
  virtual void method2();

protected:
  Context* _context;
};

#endif
```

Then the `Context` will be something like (note `State* state;`):

```
#ifndef INPUTESTATECONTEXT_H
#define INPUTESTATECONTEXT_H

#include "State.hpp"

class State;

class Context
{
private:
  State* state;
public:
  Context();
  void setState(State* new_state);
};

#endif
```

The implementation of the function to change the state is the following and it will be called from the concrete implementation of the State classes:

```
void Context::setState(InputState* new_state)
{
  state = new_state;
}
```

The constructor must initialize the `state` member:

Context::Context() 
{
  state = new State(this);
}

We are passing `this` because all the `State` classes need a reference to the `Context`.

Then we have the concrete implementation of the base `State`

```
#include "State.hpp"

class ConcreteState1 : public State
{
public:
  ConcreteState1(Context* context);
  void method1(int x, int y);
  void method2();

};

#include "State.hpp"

class ConcreteState2 : public State
{
public:
  ConcreteState1(Context* context);
  void method1(int x, int y);
  void method2();

};
```

These two classes will differ for the implementation of their member functions.

From the `Context` class you will call this methods with `state->method2()` without worrying which state is currently active (`state` is the pointer to the current state).

**To finally answer your question** Suppose in `ConcreteState1::method1(int int)` you find a condition for which you need to change the state to `ConcreteState2`. This can be achieved with the following:

```
_context->setState( new ConcreteState2(_context) );
```

After changing the state you must clean the memory from the `ConcreteState` subclass since it is not needed anymore. Many people do this with `delete` (somebody correct me if there is a more elegant way):

```
_context->setState( new ConcreteState2(_context) );
delete this;
```

Also note that all classes need also a proper destructor method to delete the pointer initialized with `new`.

One problem in your code was also that you were doing:

```
delete this;
_state = new_state;
```

this delete the object but then you are assigning a value to one of its member. I do not think this works.

I tried to be concise but if something is not clear let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this question is a little old now though, I have solved all these issues : )).  But in answer to your usage of delete - yes there is, its called `unique_ptr`. When you reset the pointer (say to point to the new state) it will automatically delete the old object.

Comment: I imagined that but I am facing your problem and wanted to share my solution to find a better one.